# É correto usar a expressão "Erro de ortografia"?

Tags: ortografia, expressões

Frequentemente vemos e ouvimos as pessoas falarem que uma determinada forma de se escrever uma palavra é um **erro de ortografia**. No entanto, a palavra *ortografia*, [segundo a Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortografia):

> deriva das palavras gregas ortho (ορθο no alfabeto grego) que significa "correto" e graphos (γραφος) que significa "escrita".

Por isso, já ouvi dizer que a expressão **erro de ortografia** é incorreta e contraditória, pois não faria sentido falar em um erro de algo (a grafia) que é correto. Seguindo essa linha, a expressão correta deveria ser **erro de grafia**.

[Esta página](http://conhecimentopratico.uol.com.br/linguaportuguesa/gramatica-ortografia/42/artigo290468-1.asp) diz que a expressão é um pleonasmo, mas eu discordo, pois ao meu ver um pleonasmo nesse caso seria algo como "*ortografia correta*".

Existe alguma regra na língua portuguesa sobre isso? A expressão é mesmo incorreta, ou pode ser utilizada normalmente?

Comment: My guess is that it's fine. In English, we tolerate public relations people speaking of an "error in judgment", even though judgment means "the faculty of deciding rightly"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**PORTUGUÊS (English follows)**

A ortografia é a parte da gramática normativa que ensina a escrever corretamente as palavras de uma língua.
Você tem um erro ortográfico quando você não cumpre as regras ortográficas.

Portanto, o termo "erro de ortografia" é correto.

Uma expressão equivalente é usada em várias línguas românicas:

Espanhol: *falta de ortografía*
Francês: *faute d'orthographe*
Italiano: *errore d'ortografia*

> Erro de ortografia: é um erro na aplicação das regras da escrita
>   correta.

---

**ENGLISH**

*Ortografía* (ortography) is part of the normative grammar that teaches how to properly write the words of a language.
You have *um erro ortográfico* (a typo) when you do not comply with the spelling rules.

Therefore, the term *erro de ortografia* is correct.

An equivalent expression is used in various Romance languages:

Spanish: *falta de ortografía*
French: *faute d'orthographe*
Italian: *errore d'ortografia*

> *Erro de ortografia*: It is an error in the application of the rules of correct writing.